# how to pivot a table in mysql by 'ip'

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

How to convert lines into columns using MYSQL?
In excel and SQL Server its ok, but what about MYSQL (i´ve done lots of errors and found lots of code but not working)...

How to convert this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iR36.jpg)

Into this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgWkc.jpg)

Database name is: 'cuestionariosB'
table name is: 'rating_details'

i´ve tried all ways of pivote and case, extract...im desperate

I expect to create columns ordered by IP.

Comment: Does column number can vary or it would be a static list which is present in image?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Also, can you include your attempt with using `CASE` in your description?

Comment: Images aren't reusable data as text is better either in question or sqlfiddle.

Comment: Try googling mysql conditional aggregation and mysql pivot.

Comment: Thanks guys for the response! I´ve manually added columns. And works perfectly!!! but...how to insert the result in a new table and configure to receive new php data and order dynamically?

Comment: Just use `INSERT INTO table_name (col_1, col_2 ....)  <select_query_from_answer>`. @PedroChica, it solves your problem, do accept the answer.

Comment: An automated way to generate the code (and run it):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually add all possible columns that you want to generate.

```
SELECT 
    T.IP,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'acceso', T.rate, NULL)) AS acceso,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'calidad instrumental', T.rate , NULL)) AS calid_instr,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'cita', T.rate, NULL)) AS cita,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'claridad_explicacion', T.rate, NULL)) AS clarid_exp,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'comodidad_espera', T.rate, NULL)) AS comodidad_espera,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'comodidad_gabinete', T.rate, NULL)) AS comodidad_gab,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'coordinacion_equipo', T.rate, NULL)) AS coordi_equipo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'detalle_explicacion', T.rate, NULL)) AS detalle_exp,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(T.title = 'edad', T.rate, NULL)) AS edad             -- For more column, you need to add further columns in same way
FROM cuestionariosB.rating_details T
GROUP BY T.IP
ORDER BY T.IP
```

To insert this result in table(temp_table)

```
INSERT INTO temp_table 
(ip, acceso, calid_instr, cita .....)   -- pick col from table in same order as upper select query
<use_uppper_select_query>
```

Make sure you have a table with proper structure to hold data.

Comment: @Pedro Chica, if it works for you, do accept the answer. :) [Accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)